# PHP OR surprising behavior

Tags: php

I have some surprising results using OR as a logical OR in php.
Considering the following code:

```
$a = false;
$b = false;
$c = true;

# Test 1, using OR and assigning to a variable
$value = $a OR $b OR $c;
var_dump( $value );
# return bool(false) but why?

# Test 2, using OR directly in var_dump
var_dump( $a OR $b OR $c );
# return bool(true) as expected

# Test 3, using || and assigning to a variable
$value = $a || $b || $c;
var_dump( $value );
# return bool(true) as expected

# Test 4, using || directly in var_dump
var_dump( $a || $b || $c );
# return bool(true) as expected
```

Why Test 1 and Test 2 give different results even though they do the same logical operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `||` operator and `OR` operator do not behave the same. They cannot be used interchangably.

If you want `||` behaviour, then use it. Do not use `OR` unless you're in a situation where `||` would do the wrong thing.

As for your situation, these two lines of code will behave exactly the same:

```
$value = $a OR $b OR $c;
($value = $a) OR $b OR $c;
```

In other words, your code is basically just:

```
$value = $a;
```

If you used the `||` operator, then these two are identical as if you had braces like this:

```
$value = $a || $b || $c;
$value = ($a || $b || $c);
```

For more details: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Totally, I would hate to live in a world where `OR` and `||` are the same thing

Comment: This answer need the link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Indeed it makes sense if OR has a lower precedence than =. Having logical operators with a lower precedence than an assignment operator feels a little unnatural though. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap test 1 in parenthesis, it will behave as expected:

```
$value = ($a OR $b OR $c);
```

When you run var_dump on test 2, you get the expected result because var_dump is wrapping the operation in parenthesis.

It is usually a good idea to wrap an operation in parenthesis like this, especially with variable assignment.

Also, the "OR" keyword and "||" do not behave the same way. See documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Of course they don't!